# Style specific tab using Tablayout and ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm looking for a way how to style tabs independently like following image:
[image]

In this case we have different icon, background color and tabIndicator color.
Looks like needs to be programmatically because tabs are loaded base on pager adapter.

**UPDATE**

After applying @Chhatrasal Singh Bundela answer
[image]

Seams to have a padding in the tab, do you know how to make it take all tab area.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me using the below code.

layout: item_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_tabTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tab text here"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

public String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3", "Tab 4"};

```
new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(baseActivity).inflate(R.layout.item_tab, null, false);
                TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textView_tabTitle);
                tv.setText(demoCollectionPagerAdapter.tabTitles[position]);
                FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(baseActivity);
                frameLayout.addView(v);
                tab.setCustomView(v);
            }
        }
        ).attach();
```

Comment: Good solution if you want to retain TextView font style when click other tabs. Also have in mind that TabLayout style won't apply for these new tabs. So you should change a behaviour by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TabLayoutMediator` class to use viewpager2 with `TabLayout`. The callback gives you privilege to customize each tab of the `TabLayout`.

```
new TabLayoutMediator(mBinding.tabLayout,
                mBinding.viewPager,
                new TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        // tab -> refernce of the tab & position -> position of the tab
                        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
                        //build your customView .
                        frameLayout.addView(/*Add all the child views. */);
                                      //or
                        //inflate your customView xml.
                        tab.setCustomView(frameLayout);
                    }
                })
                .attach();;
```