# Custom Tab layout with ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am trying to use custom tabs for my `ViewPager2` via the `TabLayout.Tab.setCustomView` method. But it doesn't work.

Here is a code snippet from my `Activity` for preparing the `ViewPager2` with a `TabLayout`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
   
   mMyViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   mMyViewPager2.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));
   mMyTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.media_tab);
   new TabLayoutMediator(mMyTabLayout, mMyViewPager2, myTabHandler).attach();
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
{
   ...
}
```

And here is the code snippet for my `TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy` (also inside my `Activity`):

```
private TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy myTabHandler = new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy()  
{
    private TextView tabTitle;
    private TextView tabSubtitle;

    @Override
    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position)
    {
        View tabView = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null, false);

        tabTitle    = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        tabSubtitle = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_subtitle);
        
        tabTitle.setText("Title" + (position + 1));
        tabSubtitle.setText("Subtitle" + (position + 1));

        tab.setCustomView(tabView);
    }
}
```

But with the above setup, the tabs remain blank.

I've also tried the following approach in my `TabConfigurationStrategy` (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148494/style-specific-tab-using-tablayout-and-viewpager2)); but it doesn't work, either:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(MyActivity.this);
frameLayout.addView(tabView);
```

I'd like to know what is wrong with my code, and how can I correct it to show custom tab layouts with `ViewPager2`.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Just to be sure: you know that "tabs" are just the headers about the pages of the viewpager? I don't use custom layout for them. With ViewPager2 you can set the text ("title") and an icon by TabLayoutMediator. I didn't want to use TabLayoutMediator at first because I wanted TabItems from the layout but it seems you have to use it and TabItems from xml are useless...

Answer (score 1):

From [`setCustomView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.Tab#setcustomview_1) documentation:

> If the provided view contains a TextView with an ID of text1 then that
> will be updated with the value given to setText(CharSequence)

So try changing the tabTitle's Id to `"@android:id/text1"`.

Now for the subtitle, I am not certain of this. Using`"@android:id/text2"` might be worth a try. Note: `"@android:id/text2"` exists.

Nevertheless, you can apply your own layout declaratively to the [`TabItems`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabItem) using [`android:layout=""`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabItem#tabitem_android_layout), thus negating the need for you to do it programmatically. There is an example of the declarative version in the `TabLayout` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout). So I believe something like this would work:

```
<TabLayout
        ...>

     <TabItem
            ....
             android:layout="@layout/linearLayout_tabitem_1"/>

     <TabItem 
             ....
             android:layout="@layout/linearLayout_tabitem_2"/>

 </TabLayout>
```

Comment: The two TextViews were just for example; I need to inflate my entirely custom tab layout. Hence your 1st solution doesn't work.

Comment: About your 2nd solution (via TabItems), I tried and nothing appeared in the tabs. Can you please provide the full implementation?

Comment: _The two TextViews were just for example; I need to inflate my entirely custom tab layout. Hence your 1st solution doesn't work._



The TextView can be part of you custom tabitem layout. What does your custom tab layout contain?

Comment: I have added a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Kalaiz/b7a9337df5a6d7dfccd0ef94d4fd2e89) for an layout file for a simple use case. Please provide your custom tab item layout, if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the the title of tabs in your pagerAdapter itself.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
   MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager() , 2);
   mMyTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.media_tab);
   mMyViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mMyTabLayout));
   mMyViewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
   mMyTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mMyViewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            setTabView(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}

private void setTabView(int index) {

    TabLayout.Tab tab = mMyTabLayout.getTabAt(index);
    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout);
    ((TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tabSubtitle)).setText("Subtitle" + (position + 1));
}



private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
   private Context mContext;
   private int mCount;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm , int count) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return someFragment();
        else if (position == 1)
            return someOtherFragment(); 



    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Title" + position+1;
            case 1:
                return "Title" + position+1;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; but you are using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, which is for ViewPager. For ViewPager2 adapter I have to extend FragmentStateAdapter which doesn't have a setTabView method.

Comment: setTabView is your own defined method not an overridden method

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Here are the steps:

1. Create a custom layout for tab item e.g. layout/tab_item
2. In the activity/fragment, set it as follows

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position -> 

    when(position) {
        0 -> {
            val tabItemBinding = TabItemBinding.inflate(layoutInftater)
            tabItemBinding.textView.text = "Some title"
            tab.customView = tabItemBinding.root
        }
        1 -> {
            // Repeat above
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps if anyone still having problems.